# pmd rule overridable method called during object construction

Tags: java, pmd

I am initializing some member variables in my DTO via setters from inside the constructor.

But the below pmd error showing so how to eliminate that pmd rule violation?

Overridden method 'setAbc' called during object construction

```
class A{

private String x;

public getX(){
return x;
}
public setX(String x){
this.x = x ;
}
A(){}

A(B b){
setX("C");
}
```

}

Comment: What's the most important is to understand why PMD shows this error. Once understood, you will also understand how to avoid it, and avoid making the mistake again.

Comment: I recommend you to read  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about making method `setX` final? Or perhaps event the entire class?